# domain user can not logon new computer

Tags: active-directory, windows-10

I have a problem on a new computer. Only one user on all my AD can not connect on the computer, and she never used it, so no Regedit value for her... Did you have a solution? AD is based on Win2008 server and this is a Win10 computer.

Edit : I tried to connect to another machine, this one under Windows 7. And it worked (infact it doesn't work on all win10 computer). So there would be a rule in the active directory that would not be compatible with Windows 10? The AD runs on a Windows Server 2008.

Comment: What do you mean by "can not connect on the computer"? How is she connecting? What error message does it give?

Comment: The error occurs when logging on to the machine, via the login screen, with its password and user name.

Comment: What is the error message that she gets?

Comment: The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.

Comment: That's a problem with that Windows 10 machine, not AD. Take a look here (there are 3 potential fixes): https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/947215/you-receive-a-the-user-profile-service-failed-the-logon-error-message

Comment: I already tried these three methods, none worked

Comment: You deleted the profile and the entry in the registry (like in method 3)?

Comment: i do not have profile, because she never log on this machine. Only my admin account was setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, one of the IT created the employee's login by copying one exist, but did not chngé the path of it, as long as one was under windows 7 and the other under Windows 10, no worries, but as soon as the two are at the same time under Windows 10, the crash. Thanks for the help and sorry, I should have thought to check that first ...